# Bump/normal/displacement maps with 3d photo

Tags: texturing, uv

my question is this, can I generate a displacement map from a 3d image, I have a 3d photo, or 2d stereo pair photos, so I've Not found any softwares or method to create a bump specular diplacement maps.

Can You help me ?
thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you alreads have found a software, what should we help you with? In general it is possible to calculate depth from stereo images, but even if you know the orientation and position of the cameras this is a rather complicated task and might not give you perfect results. And I don't think Blender can help you much here, except if you want to model the contents of the image by hand.

Comment: No the problem is that I've not found any software, sorry for error I fix soon as possible

Comment: Ok, now your question makes sense ;) But as I said, in theory you can reconstruct those parts of your scene that are visible in both images, but it is very hard to calculate and Blender has no built-in tools for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a program called Photosculpt that does what you want. [Here's](http://photosculpt.net/) a link to their site. And [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0jt9z6xPMk) a Youtube video of their software in action. There's a free trial and several price points, the cheapest of which is 139 Euros for an individual license.

Basically, you give it two photos of the same thing from slightly different angles and it spits out actual geometry as well as a normal map.